# Using video codecs like XVid in c#

Tags: c#, directshow, codec, directshow.net

I'm trying to develop an application which captures a series of images from web cam using DirectShow.Net and then sends it over network to other clients.
Everything is working fine, except the images are too big and compression methods like using GZipStream, JPEG Compression and etc does not help more about reducing the size.

Now, I want to know how to using codecs like XVid or any other codec, to reduce the size.
Playing around the demos of VisioForge, it approves that XVid files are too smaller than regular AVI files.

Thanks for any help

Comment: use ffmpeg to convert video form one format to another. Here is the link http://ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you getting raw image data from the webcam?  If so then the compression techniques you tried should help significantly.  The lossy jpeg compression can yield approx. 15 - 20 times compression, though you get to control this factor of course, but the point is, that's a serious reduction in size.  Or, can you elaborate on how the "images are too big"?

Answer (score 3):

There are specific video compression algorithms, which effectively compress video, some of the most popular are: M-JPEG, MPEG-4, H.261, H.263, H.264, VP8, Theora. In DirectShow the video compression items have form-factor of video compression filters (or codecs). Standard Windows does not normally include much for this task (for various reasons, patents to specifically mention), so you need to use a third party or otherwise installable codec. Luckily, the codecs have more or less uniform interface and you use them similarly from C#.

See related questions with helpful information:

- [Real-time video encoding in DirectShow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167032/real-time-video-encoding-in-directshow)
- [Capturing webcam using DirectShow.NET library](http://dashingquill.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/capturing-webcam-using-directshow-net-library/)

Be sure to check [DirectShow.NET samples](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/) out:

`\Samples\Misc\DxWebCam`

> A poor man's web cam program. This application runs as a Win32
>   Service.   It takes the output of a capture graph, turns it into a
>   stream of JPEG  files, and sends it thru TCP/IP to a client
>   application.

`\Samples\Capture\CapWMV`

> A .NET sample application using the WM ASF Writer filter to create an
>   wmv file

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But since I'm not familiar with Direct show SDK, and just trying to use DirectShow.NET in my project, I'm looking for an example of how to use codecs inDirectShow.Net. The DxWebCam sample of DirectShow.Net is a nice sample, but it still does not use any codec (or anything to compress images).

Comment: DirectShow is not available with .NET interface, so DirectShow.NET is the wrapper to interface DirectShow functionality from managed code. So, you will have to look into original MSDN DirectShow docs for details. Samples are limited, DirectShow.NET `DxTuner` sample uses real video compression codecs (search for `FilterCategory.VideoCompressorCategory`).