# Direct Show Decrease Video File Size

Tags: c#, video, directshow

I am using direct show to capture video and save it to file.  I have tried in vain to find ways to decrease the resultant video size but cannot manage.  I would like to know if anyone can tell me how I can:

1. Decrease the frame rate of the video
2. Decrease the quality of the video (even down to 320 x 240)
3. Apply a compression on the video (mpeg? etc).

Answer (score 1):

Raw video is huge in size, and to size-efficient storage assumes you compress the video. You are to use one of the video encoders, such as MPEG-4 AVC (H.264) or Windows Media. You typically insert an additional filter into your pipeline between capture filter and multiplexer/file writer. Read up on this in multiple past topics:

- [Using video codecs like XVid in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777246/using-video-codecs-like-xvid-in-c-sharp)
- [Real-time video encoding in DirectShow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167032/real-time-video-encoding-in-directshow)
- [How to properly build a directshow graph to compress video...](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/ae22a924-d61c-4449-b5bd-98f8eede94a4)